# Remove only first two character from a column in a dataframe using pandas

Tags: python, pandas

how can I want to remove only the first 2 characters in a string that starts with **11**

**My df** :

```
             Product1       Id
0    Waterproof Liner   114890
1        Phone Tripod   981150
2    Waterproof Pants        0
3  baby Kids play Mat  1198547
4    Hiking BACKPACKS   113114
5     security Camera   111160
Product1    object
Id          object
dtype: object
```

**Expected output:**

```
             Product1      Id
0    Waterproof Liner    4890
1        Phone Tripod  981150
2    Waterproof Pants       0
3  baby Kids play Mat   98547
4    Hiking BACKPACKS    3114
5     security Camera    1160
```

*I write this*

```
df1['Id'] = df1['Id'].str.replace("11","")
```

But i got this **output:**

```
             Product1     Id
0    Waterproof Liner   4890
1        Phone Tripod   9850
2    Waterproof Pants      0
3  baby Kids play Mat  98547
4    Hiking BACKPACKS     34
5     security Camera     60
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Force match on beginning:

```
df1['Id'] = df1['Id'].str.replace("^11","")
```